# How do I set the background color of my main screen in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm learning Flutter, and I'm starting from the very basics. I'm not using MaterialApp. What's a good way to set the background color of the whole screen?

Here's what I have so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(child: new Text("Hello, World!"));
  }
}
```

Some of my questions are:

- What's a basic way to set the background color?
- What exactly am I looking at, on the screen? Which code "is" the background? Is there a thing to set the background color on? If not, what's a simple and appropriate "simple background" (in order to paint a background color).

Thanks for the help!

The code above generates a black screen with white text:
[image]

Comment: Scaffold backgroundColor property is the most used way I think. But there are many other ways depends on your scenario. check this out.. [4 Ways To Set Background Color In Flutter](http://androidride.com/set-background-color-in-flutter/)

Answer (score 216):

You can set background color to All Scaffolds in application at once.

Just set `scaffoldBackgroundColor:` in `ThemeData`:

```
MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: new ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEFEFEF)),
    home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
);
```

Comment: This is what is required to have the same background color across all pages (scaffolds mostly). Thanks.

Comment: Great answer, especially if you use routing and navigation (much better than creating a higher-order widget from Skaffold and use it on all top-level widgets).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using the same implementation but the `scaffoldBackgroundColor` seems to be missing from child screen.

Comment: OK.  This helped me, but now I don't have borders on most of my widgets like text boxes.  Some have the borders when I hover over the widgets.

Answer (score 127):

I think you can also use a scaffold to do the white background. Here's some piece of code that may help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
      return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Testing',
        home: new Scaffold(
        //Here you can set what ever background color you need.
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to give blue color for border and amber for container background color, how can i do?

Answer (score 57):

Here's one way that I found to do it. I don't know if there are better ways, or what the trade-offs are.

[Container](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) "tries to be as big as possible", according to https://flutter.io/layout/.  Also, Container can take a `decoration`, which can be a [BoxDecoration](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html), which can have a `color` (which, is the background color).

Here's a sample that does indeed fill the screen with red, and puts "Hello, World!" into the center:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
      child: new Center(
        child: new Text("Hello, World!"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note, the Container is returned by the MyApp build(). The Container has a decoration and a child, which is the centered text.

See it in action here:

[image]

Comment: Container is a good choice if you're building a simple app or an app that isn't using Material design. If you're building a Material app, consider using ThemeData.dark() if you want a dark background on all your canvases and cards. You can also get fine-grained control over card and canvas background colors using the cardColor and canvasColor arguments to the ThemeData constructor. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ThemeData/ThemeData.html

Comment: what about setting custom RGB?

Comment: i want to give blue color for border and amber for container background color, how can i do?

Comment: I am not using Scaffold and this solution is incredible. Thanks.

Comment: @CollinJackson What if you are using Material but don't have a Scaffold for every page? Would you still suggest a container or something else?

Answer (score 43):

There are many ways of doing it, I am listing few here.

1. Using `backgroundColor`

   ```
   Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Colors.black,
     body: Center(...),
   )
   ```
2. Using `Container` in `SizedBox.expand`

   ```
   Scaffold(
     body: SizedBox.expand(
       child: Container(
         color: Colors.black,
         child: Center(...)
       ),
     ),
   )
   ```
3. Using `Theme`

   ```
   Theme(
     data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black),
     child: Scaffold(
       body: Center(...),
     ),
   )
   ```

Answer (score 9):

You should return **Scaffold** widget and add your widget inside **Scaffold**

Such as this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Center(child: new Text("Hello, World!"));
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Your App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black, 
      ),
      home HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's another approach to change the color of background:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(backgroundColor: Colors.pink,),);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Constants.defaulBackground,
      body: new Container(
      child: Center(yourtext)

      )
)
```

Comment: Whilst this code may solve the issue, you should always explain why/how your code works.

Answer (score 5):

On the basic example of Flutter you can set with `backgroundColor: Colors.X` of Scaffold

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: Center(
            // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
            // in the middle of the parent.
            child: Column(
                // Column is also layout widget. It takes a list of children and
                // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
                // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
                //
                // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
                // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
                // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
                // to see the wireframe for each widget.
                //
                // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
                // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
                // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
                // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
                // horizontal).
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                        'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                    ),
                    Text(
                        '$_counter',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _incrementCounter,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
        ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to use `MaterialApp` widget and use `theme` and set  `primarySwatch` with color that you want. look like below code,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor:  Color(
                0xBF453F3F),
```

and done :)

Answer (score 3):

You can just put the six digit hexa after (0xFF**......**):

```
return Scaffold( 
    backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFE9ECEF),
.....) } )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define the background color globally in your app theme:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(41, 45, 42, 1),
```

Or for one page:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent, //<-- SEE HERE
    appBar: ...,
    body: ...,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Sample App'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,  // changing Appbar back color
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,     // changing body back color
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As sirelon suggested, add scaffold color in the theme like this,

```
theme: new ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEFEFEF)),
```

or can give color to individual scaffold like this

```
Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF1F1F1),
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white, // Change the background color of all Scaffold widgets of your app here
      ),
      home: const Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: Text("Hello, World!")),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white, // Change the background color of this Scaffold widget here
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to change color at app level you can to it via themedata -> canvasColor

```
GetMaterialApp(
                theme: ThemeData(
                  canvasColor: Colors.white)
```