# FLUTTER: How to make a persitent background image for app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to use the same background image for all screen in my app, make it static so it don't move when I use navigator. Do you have an idea how to do that ?

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822671/how-do-i-set-the-background-color-of-my-main-screen-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can define a widget with a background image and stack your desired screen on top of that.

```
class BackgroundPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const BackgroundPage({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  /// The widget to display
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: ExactAssetImage('image.png'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```