# How to change white to blue background

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm still learning on how to use flutter. Tried flutter demo page. Now just want to change color. Managed to change the banner color. Now having difficulties in changing the background color of center. How to change the background color at the center from white to blue.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        
        primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: '200545'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

 
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
   
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        
        child: Column(
          
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822671/how-do-i-set-the-background-color-of-my-main-screen-in-flutter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the background color of my main screen in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822671/how-do-i-set-the-background-color-of-my-main-screen-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

`Scaffold` provides `backgroundColor`  that can be used to change background color.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue, //this
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: Center(
```

Also, you can use theme for this and I prefer using `copyWith`

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      appBarTheme: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.copyWith(
            color: Colors.pink,
          ),
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blue // this
      ),
  home: const MyHomePage(title: '200545'),
);
```

You can check more about [themes](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes).

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change the backgroundcolor property of Scaffold same as below

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: const Color(0xffFFFFFF),/// if you want to use HEX Color code
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue, /// if you want to use color name 
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),);
```

Note:- you can use ether HEX color OR Color name not both at the same time