# How to change the background color of Syncfusion Flutter Calendar to white?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, syncfusion, syncfusion-calendar

I'm building a Flutter app using the Syncfusion calendar widget. Currently, my calendar appears with a black background, obscuring the days and numbers. I want to change the background color to white.

**Here's a screenshot:**

[image: Black Calendar Screenshot]

I suspect I need to modify color properties, but I'm not sure where to start.

**Here's my current code:**

(in my `pubspec.yaml`, I'm using `sync_fusion_calendar`)

```
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_calendar/calendar.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
 
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

late Map<DateTime, List<Appointment>> _dataCollection;

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late var _calendarDataSource;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _dataCollection = getAppointments();
    _calendarDataSource = MeetingDataSource(<Appointment>[]);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SfCalendar(
      view: CalendarView.month,
      monthViewSettings: MonthViewSettings(
          appointmentDisplayMode: MonthAppointmentDisplayMode.appointment),
      dataSource: _calendarDataSource,
      loadMoreWidgetBuilder:
          (BuildContext context, LoadMoreCallback loadMoreAppointments) {
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: loadMoreAppointments(),
          builder: (context, snapShot) {
            return Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.blue),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Map<DateTime, List<Appointment>> getAppointments() {
    final List<String> _subjectCollection = <String>[];
    _subjectCollection.add('General Meeting');
    _subjectCollection.add('Plan Execution');
    _subjectCollection.add('Project Plan');
    _subjectCollection.add('Consulting');
    _subjectCollection.add('Support');
    _subjectCollection.add('Development Meeting');
    _subjectCollection.add('Scrum');
    _subjectCollection.add('Project Completion');
    _subjectCollection.add('Release updates');
    _subjectCollection.add('Performance Check');

    final List<Color> _colorCollection = <Color>[];
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFF0F8644));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFF8B1FA9));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFFD20100));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFFFC571D));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFF36B37B));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFF01A1EF));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFF3D4FB5));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFFE47C73));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFF636363));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFF0A8043));

    final Random random = Random();
    var _dataCollection = <DateTime, List<Appointment>>{};
    final DateTime today = DateTime.now();
    final DateTime rangeStartDate = DateTime(today.year, today.month, today.day)
        .add(const Duration(days: -1000));
    final DateTime rangeEndDate = DateTime(today.year, today.month, today.day)
        .add(const Duration(days: 1000));
    for (DateTime i = rangeStartDate;
    i.isBefore(rangeEndDate);
    i = i.add(Duration(days: 1 + random.nextInt(2)))) {
      final DateTime date = i;
      final int count = 1 + random.nextInt(3);
      for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        final DateTime startDate = DateTime(
            date.year, date.month, date.day, 8 + random.nextInt(8), 0, 0);
        final int duration = random.nextInt(3);
        final Appointment meeting = Appointment(
            subject: _subjectCollection[random.nextInt(7)],
            startTime: startDate,
            endTime:
            startDate.add(Duration(hours: duration == 0 ? 1 : duration)),
            color: _colorCollection[random.nextInt(9)],
            isAllDay: false);

        if (_dataCollection.containsKey(date)) {
          final List<Appointment> meetings = _dataCollection[date]!;
          meetings.add(meeting);
          _dataCollection[date] = meetings;
        } else {
          _dataCollection[date] = [meeting];
        }
      }
    }
    return _dataCollection;
  }
}

class MeetingDataSource extends CalendarDataSource {
  MeetingDataSource(List<Appointment> source) {
    appointments = source;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> handleLoadMore(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    final List<Appointment> meetings = <Appointment>[];
    DateTime appStartDate = startDate;
    DateTime appEndDate = endDate;

    while (appStartDate.isBefore(appEndDate)) {
      final List<Appointment>? data = _dataCollection[appStartDate];
      if (data == null) {
        appStartDate = appStartDate.add(Duration(days: 1));
        continue;
      }
      for (final Appointment meeting in data) {
        if (appointments!.contains(meeting)) {
          continue;
        }
        meetings.add(meeting);
      }
      appStartDate = appStartDate.add(Duration(days: 1));
    }
    appointments!.addAll(meetings);
    notifyListeners(CalendarDataSourceAction.add, meetings);
  }
}
```

Can anyone guide me on how to set the background color of the Syncfusion calendar to white?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the background color of my main screen in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822671/how-do-i-set-the-background-color-of-my-main-screen-in-flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the sfcalendar with a scaffold. And give sfcalendar as the body of the scaffold

```
Scaffold(
body: SFCalendar()
)
```

Comment: great, should vote this as answer. Tq